# Import a list of replacement rules for later use

Tags: list-manipulation, import, rule

I have a do-loop in which I use recursively a NMinimize process and gives a result of the form

```
in: Do[NMinimize[f[i,V0,rd,d,n],{V0,rd,d,n}], {i,1,3}]

out:{V0 -> 200.700, rd -> 7.68528, d -> 0.722816, n -> 1.0}
    {V0 -> 202.828, rd -> 7.46368, d -> 0.255458, n -> 1.0}
    {V0 -> 208.434, rd -> 7.46236, d -> 0.479465, n -> 1.0}
```

I want to store that same result in a .txt file for later use as replacement lists, say:

```
VELO[V0,rd,d,n]/.{V0 -> 200.700, rd -> 7.68528, d -> 0.722816, n -> 1.0};
VELO[V0,rd,d,n]/.{V0 -> 202.828, rd -> 7.46368, d -> 0.255458, n -> 1.0};
VELO[V0,rd,d,n]/.{V0 -> 208.434, rd -> 7.46236, d -> 0.479465, n -> 1.0};
```

where `VELO[V0,rd,d,n]` is a function of the four parameters. I export the file as

```
Do[Write[bestfit, MINREDCHISQRAT[i][[2]]];
   , {i, 1, 3}];
  Close["bestfit.txt"]
 ]
```

When I attempt to do it, and later I import the .txt file

```
Import["C:\\Users\\psrot\\bestfit.txt", "Table"]
```

I get something like

```
    {{{V0, ->, 200.7, rd, ->, 7.68528, d, ->,0.722816, n, ->, 1.0}}, 
{{V0, ->, 202.828, rd, ->, 7.46368, d, ->, 0.255458, n, ->, 1.0}}, {{V0, ->,
       208.434, rd, ->, 7.46236, d, ->, 0.479465, n, 
      ->, 1.0}}}
```

which I can't use as a replacement because of the COMMAS.

My question is: How can I save the replacement lists in such a way that when I import the .txt that contains them, I could use them to evaluate my function in a do-loop for each set of parameters?

PS: I put only 3 as the steps of the do-loop, in reality I have more than 1000 steps.

Comment: What is the output of `MINREDCHISQRAT[i][[2]]` for one of the `i`s?

Comment: Try `Import["C:\\Users\\psrot\\bestfit.txt", "Package"]`.

Comment: thank you very much dear @J.M. but i only manage to load the last element of the file, not the others, which i need for another loop evaluation

Answer (score 2):

I already found it, it is enough to import as:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\psrot\\bestfit.txt", "List"]
```

and then

```
ToExpression@ %[[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadList` is your friend:

```
ReadList["C:\\Users\\psrot\\bestfit.txt"]
```